# Как сделать авторизацию через учетную запись SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Как авторизоваться с помощью учетной записи Microsoft SQL Server?
Регистрация аккаунта получается, а авторизацию не понимаю как сделать.

Строка коннекта:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=Name; Database=db; User ID=" + textBoxLogin.Text.ToString() + "; Password=" + textBoxPassword.ToString());
```

Пытаюсь зайти под админом sa.
Ошибка: `При входе в систему пользователя "sa" произошла ошибка.`

Аккаунт sa включен. В настройках сервера включена проверка подлинности SQL Server и Windows.

Скорей всего нужно добавить что-то еще в строку коннекта, но не знаю чего(

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh136722(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поискав на MSDN всё таки наткнулся на пример и теперь всё работает:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" + textBoxLogin.Text + ";Password=" + textBoxPassword.Text + ";Initial Catalog=db;Server=ServerName");
```